# Spring REST error handling : Cannot have my custom message

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I read several articles/tutorials... about error handling on server side. I simply want to return an http error code with my custom message. And of course it does not work.

The result I'm always having in my javascript callbacks is this message :

`<html><head><style type="text/css">*{margin:0px;padding:0px;background:#fff;}</style><title>HTTP ERROR</title><script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://static.worlderror.org/http/error.js"></script></head><body><iframe src="http://www.worlderror.org/http/?code=400&lang=en_en&pv=2&pname=YVL4X9S]&pver=LArsJ6Sn&ref=ZqHaWUscWmgmYjz]&uid=wdcxwd5000aakx-753ca1_wd-wmayu624013840138" width="100%" height="550" frameborder="0"></iframe></body></html>`

My code :
Javascript :

```
create : function() {
    $scope.myObject.$save(
    function(response) {
         init();
         $scope.popupCtrl.hideModal();
         $scope.popupCtrl.hideError();
    },
    function(error) {
        // error, where I always get the html page...
        $scope.popupCtrl.manageError(error.message);
    });
}
```

My Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myObject", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public final String createNewCrawlConfiguration(@RequestBody final String receivedString)
{
    String jsonString;
    try
    {
        jsonString = URLDecoder.decode(receivedString, "UTF-8");
        LOGGER.debug("Preparing configuration to be saved. Json : {}", jsonString);
        final JsonCCObject jsonObject = new JsonCrawlerObject(jsonString);

        // check for the json*
        // validate contains an array of missing attributes.

        if (!jsonObject.validate().isEmpty())
        {
            throw new ConfigurationCreationException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                    returnJsonError(new ArrayList<>(jsonObject.validate())));
        }

        // save the object

    }
    catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        throw new ConfigurationCreationException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                "Unsupported encoding : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (final JSONException e)
    {
        throw new ConfigurationCreationException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                "Json Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (final DuplicateKeyException e)
    {
        throw new ConfigurationCreationException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                "Configuration portant le meme nom deja existante");
    }
    return buildReturnMessage("ok", "Crawling configuration correctly added");
}

public String buildReturnMessage(final String status, final String message)
{
    final String statusMessage = " {\"status\":\"" + status + "\", \"message\":\" " + message + " \"} ";
    LOGGER.debug(statusMessage);
    return statusMessage;
}

/**
 * Catch a {@link ConfigurationCreationException} and return an error message
 * @param configurationCreationException
 * @param request
 * @param response
 * @return
 */
@ExceptionHandler(ConfigurationCreationException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public String handleConfigurationCreationException(
        final ConfigurationCreationException configurationCreationException,
        final WebRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
{
    LOGGER.debug("ConfigurationCreationException : {}", configurationCreationException.getErrMessage());
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    return buildReturnMessage(configurationCreationException.getErrCode(),
            configurationCreationException.getErrMessage());
}
```

Have you got any ideas ?

Thank you !

---

**EDIT**

I did a mistake on my question :

The html returned shows error 400.
I haven't any media problem, it's the error I want to return. What I mean is that tomcat is not generating it, I do it myself with a `throw new ConfigurationCreationException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,...)`.

**The issue here is only about retrieving the custom error on the client side :/.**

Comment: I have implemented this but still am getting html page as a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this :

I updated my Spring version from `3.2.2` to `4.0.3` (a more recent should work too).

Then, `@ControllerAdvice` accepts the `basePackage` parameters :

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "me.myself.hi")
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{
    /** The associated logger. */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { HttpRestException.class })
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(final RuntimeException ex, final WebRequest request)
    {
        if (ex instanceof HttpRestException)
        {
            final HttpRestException restEx = (HttpRestException) ex;
            return handleExceptionInternal(ex, restEx.getMessage(), new HttpHeaders(), restEx.getHttpStatus(), request);
        }

        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, "Internal server error",
                new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
    }
}
```

`basePackage` specify the package assigned to the handler class. That means each controller defined in this package (or a sub one) will be concerned.

For me, `me.myself.hi` is a base package name shared by at least 10 projects. So even if a controller is in another project, as long as it is under a package starting with `me.myself.hi`, the HttpRestException will be catched there.

Remember that the exception must not be handled at the Controller level, but only thrown, the `@ControllerAdvice` annotated controller will handle this exception and return statuscode + error message.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem, by writing and registering a Exception Handler that responds with an JSON encoded error message, whenever a exception is delivered to the Exception Handler, and the requests accept type header is `application/json` or `application/json; charset=utf-8`.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils;

/**
 * Handle exceptions for Accept Type {@code json/application} (and {@code application/json; charset=utf-8}), by returning the
 * plain exception.
 *
 * <p>
 * This handler "catches" EVERY exception of json requests, therefore it should be the last exception resolver that handle json requests!  
 * </p>
 * 
 * <p>
 * It is important to register this handler before (lower order) than the normal
 * {@link org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver}.
 * </p>
 * 

 * 
 * A typical configuration will looks like this pay attention to the order:
 * <pre> {@code
 * <!--
 *    dispatcher servlet:
 *        <init-param>
 *           <param-name>detectAllHandlerExceptionResolvers</param-name>
 *           <param-value>false</param-value>
 *       </init-param>
 * -->
 * <bean id="handlerExceptionResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite">
 *      <property name="exceptionResolvers">
 *          <list> 
 *              <!-- created by AnnotationDrivenBeanDefintionParser -->
 *              <ref bean="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0" />
 *              
 *              <!-- created by AnnotationDrivenBeanDefintionParser -->
 *              <ref bean="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0" />
 *          
 *                   <bean class="JsonPlainExceptionResolver">
 *                       <!-- <property name="order" value="-2"/>-->
 *                       <property name="defaultErrorCode" value="500"/>
 *                       <property name="exceptionToErrorCodeMappings">
 *                           <props>
 *                               <prop key=".DataAccessException">500</prop>
 *                               <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">404</prop>
 *                               <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">404</prop>
 *                               <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">404</prop>
 *                              <prop key=".ResourceNotFoundException">404</prop>
 *                              <prop key=".AccessDeniedException">403</prop>
 *                        </props>
 *                   </property>
 *              </bean>
 *              
 *              <!-- created by AnnotationDrivenBeanDefintionParser -->
 *              <ref bean="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0" />
 *          </list>
 *      </property>
 *  </bean>
 * }
 * </pre> 
 * </p>
 *
 * <p>
 * It is recommended to use this exception resolver together with an
 * {@link ResponseCommittedAwarenessExceptionResolverWrapper}
 * </p>
 * 
 * @author Ralph Engelmann
 */
public class JsonPlainExceptionResolver extends AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver {

    /** Logger for this class. */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(JsonPlainExceptionResolver.class);

    /** Accept header attribute for application/json. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_JSON = "application/json";

    /** Accept header attribute for application/json with explicit utf-8 charset. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

    /** The default for the {@link #defaultErrorCode}. */
    private static final int DEFAULT_DEFAULT_ERROR_CODE = 500;

    /** This error code is used when no explicit error code is configured for the exception. */
    private int defaultErrorCode = DEFAULT_DEFAULT_ERROR_CODE;

    /** Key = exception pattern, value exception code. */
    private Properties exceptionToErrorCodeMappings;

    public int getDefaultErrorCode() {
        return this.defaultErrorCode;
    }

    public void setDefaultErrorCode(final int defaultErrorCode) {
        this.defaultErrorCode = defaultErrorCode;
    }

    public Properties getExceptionToErrorCodeMappings() {
        return this.exceptionToErrorCodeMappings;
    }

    /**
     * Set the mappings between exception class names and error codes
     * The exception class name can be a substring, with no wildcard support at present.
     * A value of "ServletException" would match <code>javax.servlet.ServletException</code>
     * and subclasses, for example.

     * @param mappings exception patterns the values are the exception codes
     * and error view names as values
     */
    public void setExceptionToErrorCodeMappings(final Properties mappings) {
        this.exceptionToErrorCodeMappings = mappings;
    }

    /**
     * Check whether this resolver is supposed to apply to the given handler.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This implementation do the same checks as the super class, and requires in addition that 
     * the request has an JSON accept Type.
     * </p>
     */
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldApplyTo(HttpServletRequest request, Object handler) {

        String acceptType = request.getHeader("Accept");
        return super.shouldApplyTo(request, handler)
                && (acceptType != null)
                && (acceptType.equalsIgnoreCase(APPLICATION_JSON) || acceptType.equalsIgnoreCase(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
    }

    /**
     * Do resolve exception.
     *
     * @param request the request
     * @param response the response
     * @param handler the handler
     * @param ex the ex
     * @return an Empty Model and View this will make the DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException in conjunction with
     * DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult assume that the request is already handeled.
     * 
     * @see
     * org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver#doResolveException(javax.servlet.http
     * .HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Exception)
     */
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView doResolveException(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            final Object handler, final Exception ex) {

        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Handle exception from request: "+ request, ex);
        }

        String exceptionDetails = JsonPlainExceptionResolver.getExceptionDetailsAndCompleteStackTrace(ex);

        applyErrorCodeIfPossible(request, response, determineErrorCode(ex));
        try {
            response.getOutputStream().write(exceptionDetails.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("UTF-8 not supported???", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while writing exception " + exceptionDetails + ", to response", e);
        }

        WebUtils.clearErrorRequestAttributes(request);

        ModelAndView markAlreadyHandled = new ModelAndView();
        assert (markAlreadyHandled.isEmpty());
        return markAlreadyHandled;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver#buildLogMessage(java.lang.Exception,
     * javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
     */
    @Override
    protected String buildLogMessage(final Exception ex, final HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "Handler execution (" + ex.getClass() + ") resulted in exception , request: "
                + request);
    }

    /**
     * Determine the view name for the given exception, searching the {@link #setExceptionMappings "exceptionMappings"},
     * using the {@link #setDefaultErrorView "defaultErrorView"} as fallback.
     * @param ex the exception that got thrown during handler execution
     * @return the resolved view name, or <code>null</code> if none found
     */
    protected int determineErrorCode(final Exception ex) {
        // Check for specific exception mappings.
        if (this.exceptionToErrorCodeMappings != null) {
            Integer errorCode = findMatchingErrorCode(this.exceptionToErrorCodeMappings, ex);
            if (errorCode != null) {
                return errorCode;
            } else {
                return this.defaultErrorCode;
            }
        }
        return this.defaultErrorCode;
    }

    /**
     * Find a matching view name in the given exception mappings.
     * @param exceptionMappings mappings between exception class names and error view names
     * @param ex the exception that got thrown during handler execution
     * @return the view name, or <code>null</code> if none found
     * @see #setExceptionMappings
     */
    protected Integer findMatchingErrorCode(final Properties exceptionMappings, final Exception ex) {
        Integer errorCode = null;
        int deepest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Enumeration<?> names = exceptionMappings.propertyNames(); names.hasMoreElements();) {
            String exceptionMapping = (String) names.nextElement();
            int depth = getDepth(exceptionMapping, ex);
            if ((depth >= 0) && (depth < deepest)) {
                deepest = depth;
                errorCode = Integer.parseInt(exceptionMappings.getProperty(exceptionMapping));
            }
        }
        return errorCode;
    }

    /**
     * Return the depth to the superclass matching.
     * <p>0 means ex matches exactly. Returns -1 if there's no match.
     * Otherwise, returns depth. Lowest depth wins.
     *
     * @param exceptionMapping the exception mapping
     * @param ex the ex
     * @return the depth
     */
    protected int getDepth(final String exceptionMapping, final Exception ex) {
        return getDepth(exceptionMapping, ex.getClass(), 0);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the depth.
     *
     * @param exceptionMapping the exception mapping
     * @param exceptionClass the exception class
     * @param depth the depth
     * @return the depth
     */
    private int getDepth(final String exceptionMapping, final Class<?> exceptionClass, final int depth) {
        if (exceptionClass.getName().contains(exceptionMapping)) {
            // Found it!
            return depth;
        }
        // If we've gone as far as we can go and haven't found it...
        if (exceptionClass.equals(Throwable.class)) {
            return -1;
        }
        return getDepth(exceptionMapping, exceptionClass.getSuperclass(), depth + 1);
    }

    /**
     * Apply the specified HTTP status code to the given response, if possible (that is,
     * if not executing within an include request).
     * @param request current HTTP request
     * @param response current HTTP response
     * @param statusCode the status code to apply
     * @see #determineStatusCode
     * @see #setDefaultStatusCode
     * @see HttpServletResponse#setStatus
     */
    protected void applyErrorCodeIfPossible(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            final int statusCode) {
        if (!WebUtils.isIncludeRequest(request)) {
            response.setStatus(statusCode);
            request.setAttribute(WebUtils.ERROR_STATUS_CODE_ATTRIBUTE, statusCode);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the exception details and complete stack trace.
     *
     * @param e the e
     * @return the exception details and complete stack trace
     */
    public static String getExceptionDetailsAndCompleteStackTrace(final Throwable e) {
        StringBuilder detailedMessage = new StringBuilder();
        if (e.getLocalizedMessage() != null) {
            detailedMessage.append(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        if (detailedMessage.length() > 0) {
            detailedMessage.append("\n");
        }

        detailedMessage.append(e.getClass().getName());

        /** Save: Commons lang does not support generics in this old version. */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Throwable> throwables = ExceptionUtils.getThrowableList(e);
        for (int i = 1; i < throwables.size(); i++) {
            detailedMessage.append("\n cause: ");
            detailedMessage.append(throwables.get(i).getClass().getName());
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(throwables.get(i).getLocalizedMessage())) {
                detailedMessage.append(" -- " + throwables.get(i).getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            detailedMessage.append(";");
        }

        detailedMessage.append("\n\n --full Stacktrace--\n");
        detailedMessage.append(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));

        return detailedMessage.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: This exactly what I did years ago for this problem. While your customizing an exception resolver you might want to take a look at the MediaTypeException problem: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10226?focusedCommentId=87490&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-87490

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for replying. 
This is scaring me a bit to think that it was supposed to be so simple in tutorials..
Thank you both I'm gonna try :/

Comment: Hum, I did a mistake in my question. I havnt actually any media type problem. I built the exception myself because I want to have this error type. Tomcat is not generating it. My issue is only about retrieving the error message actually. Can your answer work in this case ?

I read your code but not fully understanded it for the moment.
Thanks again

Comment: Don't worry about my comment regarding mediat type as it was more for @Ralph. First do what Ralph recommends.

Comment: ok @AdamGent, but what Ralph suggest is so far from tutorials that it seems to be some overkill.
I'm trying today anyway :)

Comment: @ogdabou: my code maybe seems to be an overkill, because it is (hopefully) production quality, and not just some tutorial stuff that is reduced to the minimum to point something out.

Comment: @Ralph thank you :). Actually I'm trying it right now. I've a noclassfound exception I'm trying to solve ^^.

PS : I didn't meant to be mean of course, just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the worlderror.org malware installed on your computer that is intercepting the 400-600 status code responses.
Your not even seeing the spring errors because the malware is intercepting it.

Try running a different browser or run a spyware removal software.

Comment: Thank you, I had this malware :). It didn't make my old code to return a message but at least I could retrieve a normal tomcat exception page !

Answer (score 0):

I have the following and works fine:

**Note**: Doing the things simple.

In your class that extends **WebMvcConfigurerAdapter** add the following:

```
@Bean
public StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter(){
    StringHttpMessageConverter converter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver(){
    ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver eher = new ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver();
    eher.setMessageConverters(Arrays.asList(stringHttpMessageConverter()));
    return eher;
}

@Bean
public ResponseStatusExceptionResolver responseStatusExceptionResolver(){
    return new ResponseStatusExceptionResolver();
}


@Override
public void configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers){
        exceptionResolvers.add(exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver());
        exceptionResolvers.add(responseStatusExceptionResolver());
}
```

Therefore

```
@ExceptionHandler(value=MyException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> errorHandlerHttpHeaderRestrict(MyException me){
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("ERROR FATAL: "+me.getMessage(), httpHeaders, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);//400
}
```

I suggest you use `ResponseEntity` instead of
`@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)` and `@ResponseBody`.

It because:

1. `ResponseEntity` is more flexible
2. With `@ResponseStatus` you must be **totally** sure the method only can return that **HttpStatus** (just one)

Comment: I'll try thanks, I don't see any classes extending "WebMvcConfigurerAdapter", I'm searching :)

Comment: I am working with only JavaConfig, therefore I am not working with either `xml` and `web.xml`

Comment: Yeah that's what I understood, and as the project I'm working on work with `xml` and `web.xml` I'm trying Ralph answer first.

Comment: My configuration shared can be represented in XML too.