# Configure Spring to return 404 HTTP code on every null returning webmethod

Tags: java, spring, http, null, handler

I want to configure my web methods to set the http status code to 404 or an other code indicating that something went wrong (e.g. 444 No Response).

Currently the response is http 200 with null in its body.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "folder", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Folder findFolder(String folderId, WebRequest request) throws PermissionDeniedException, ServiceException {
    return projectService.findFolder(folderId); // should set HttpCode.NO_RESPONSE if the method returns null
}
```

Is there a central way to configure the web services rather than handling null  values one by one in each method?

Alternatively, is there a way to bind an @ExceptionHandler (or rather @SomeGenereicHandler) to null return values?

Comment: So I dont want to check for null values and set return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) manually

Comment: check this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26732152/957654

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send the send status code as response for 404 instead of 404.jsp as a html reponse in spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728597/how-to-send-the-send-status-code-as-response-for-404-instead-of-404-jsp-as-a-htm)

Comment: Since returning a null value is not a exception your comments are no solution to the problem.